# haskell partial application in case-statement

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble understanding whats going on in this function. My understanding is that `fmap f x` returns a function that takes the last argument `y`.  But when is `y` "fed" to `fmap f x` inside the case statement?.

```
func :: (Num a, Num b) => (a -> b -> c) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> Maybe c
func f x y = case fmap f x of
                      Nothing -> Nothing
                      Just z -> fmap z y
```

Comment: It returns a `Maybe (b -> c)`, so a function wrapped in a `Maybe`.

Comment: So the line, `Just z -> fmap z y` can be thought of as:

In the case where `fmap f x` produced `Just (Maybe (b -> c))` then `fmap (b -> c) y`

Comment: FYI, `func` is just [`liftA2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `Maybe`, the functor instance is defined as:

```
instance Functor Maybe where
    fmap _ Nothing = Nothing
    fmap f (Just x) = Just (f x)
```

So for `f ~ Maybe`, `fmap` is specialized to `fmap :: (g -> h) -> Maybe g -> Maybe h`.

In your specific case, `f` has signature `f :: a -> b -> c`, or more verbose `ff :: a -> (b -> c)`. So that means that for our signature of `fmap`, we obtain:

```
fmap :: (g ->    h    ) -> Maybe g -> Maybe h
   f ::  a -> (b -> c)
----------------------------------------------
g ~ a, h ~ (b -> c)
```

So that means `fmap f x` will have type `fmap f x :: Maybe (b -> c)`. It is thus a `Maybe` that wraps a function of type `b -> c`.

Here we thus can inspect if `fmap f x` is a `Just z`, in which case `z` has type `z :: b -> c`, or `Nothing`.

In case it is a `Just z`, we thus can perform another `fmap` with `z`, and thus obtain a `Maybe c`.